# Циклическая зависимость maven модулей!

Tags: java, spring, maven, юнит-тесты, spring-boot

есть несколько модулей в maven

```
parent
model
dao
service
console
```

все модули подключают `model` , `console` также подключает `service` ,

```
service->dao
Приложение -SpringBoot
```

пишу `unit test` для слоя `dao` , чтобы запустить тест , нужно указать класс

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
```

Который находиться в `console` , когда подключаю к `dao` , `console (scope-test)` возникает циклическая зависимость.

Как это можно обойти?

**Исходники проекта** : https://github.com/flagmen/trainsAPP

Comment: *пишу unit test для слоя dao , чтобы запустить тест , нужно указать класс @ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class)* Если unit тест зависит от внешних модулей - это уже совсем не unit тест.

Comment: зачем вам нужно подключать dao?

Comment: я подключаю не dao ,  а console , т.к. там находиться springboot класс

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем случае у вас точка входа в приложение должна зависеть от остальных модулей, а не наоборот. Из вопроса я понимаю, что это точка входа - это `Console`.

1. Если есть циклическая зависимость между кодом `Console` и `Dao`,  унесите общий код в отдельный модуль (или перенесите его в `Dao`, если это соответствует его назначению), от которого они оба будут зависеть.

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

2. Если вам для юнит-тестов нужен `ApplicationContext` из модуля `Console` - создайте отдельный изолированный контекст для теста(ов) (см. [`@SpringBootTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html), [`@TestConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/TestConfiguration.html)). Прочитайте внимательно официальную документацию по [Spring Boot Testing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html) и [Spring Testing](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html), чтобы разобраться в общепринятых подходах.

---

3. Если вы уверены, что вам нужен именно тот же контекст, что и в `Console` со всеми его компонентами, значит вы хотите написать не юнит-тест, а контрактный/интеграционный тест. Выделите для него отдельный модель, который будет брать  все необходимые зависимости.

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]